# On load on a select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a select option that when it changes it activates a script. What I'm trying to do is at the start when there is a selected value in the select option It would also activate the script. Right now here is my code

I know that onload does not work on select option. So could you give me an idea for an alternative?
Here is my code

```
<script>

function getState(val) {

    var group = $("#group").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "<?=base_url()?>personnel/get_division/"+val,
            data:{"group": group},
            success: function(data){
                $('#div1').html(data);
             }
        }); 
}
</script>

<select id="grp" name="group" class="cust_fields" onChange="getState(this.value);">

                    <option value=""> -- Select -- </option> 

                    <?php $table = "tbl_group"; $select = "g_name, g_id"; ?>

                    <?php foreach($ddl1 as $row1){ ?> 

                    <option value="<?=$row1['g_id']?>"> <?=$row1['g_name']?> </option> 

                    <?php } ?>

                </select>
```

Comment: Why can't you just have an `onload` for the `body` element instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have an onChange event tied to each element, you could trigger the event on the selected item on page load.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //$('option:selected').trigger('change');
    $('select').trigger('change');

});
```

Comment: Change event should be triggered on the select element

Comment: Nice! Beat me to the answer. Although you could just use the jQuery shorthand `$(function() { ...` instead of `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`

Comment: True, but you want to ensure the DOM is ready before triggering that event, since he is registering the event directly on the DOM element itself. Otherwise the trigger may fire before the event is registered. At least that is how I understood it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're the same: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ says that `$()` is shorthand for the `$(document).ready()` structure. But it doesn't matter. Just saying.

Comment: I would say it matters. `$()` is shorter (therefore more efficient) than `$(document).ready......` Thanks for the tip. Learn something new everyday.